# Task Parallel library waiting for method in loop to finish (.NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

wonder if you can help.

I have a listview displaying a list of Customer EG (Customer1,Customer2,Customer3 etc..)

Now each customer can have 1000s of orders to process so

The problem I have is that I would like to wait for processcustomer to finish before starting with new one,and
I dont know how to code it to make my "ProcessCustomer" in the loop to finish before can proceed with the next one.

Psuedo code below:

```
    public class form1
    {
        private void StartProcessingCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in lvwCustomers.Items)
            {
                customerPresenter.ProcessCustomer(item.Tag as Customer);
            }
        }
    }


    public class CustomerPresenter
    {
            private void ProcessCustomer(Customer customer)
            {
                CustomerProcessor customerProcessor=new CustomerProcessor();
                customerProcessor.OrderProcessing += OnCustomerProcessing;
                customerProcessor.OrderProcessed += OnCustomerProcessed;
                customerProcessor.TaskCompleted += OnCustomerCompleted;

                customerProcessor.ProcessCustomer(customer);

            }
    }

     public class CustomerProcessor
    {
        public CustomerProcessor()
        {

        }

        public void ProcessCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            //simplified version with psuedo code

            cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var parOpts = new ParallelOptions();
            parOpts.CancellationToken = cancelToken.Token;
            parOpts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1;

            const int index = 0;
            try
            {
                sw.Start();
                processResult.StartedAt = DateTime.Now;
                Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Parallel.ForEach(customer.Orders, parOpts, (order, loopState) =>
                        {
                            count = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
                            ProcessOrder(order, count);
                        });
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                       //omitted code
                    }

                }, cancelToken.Token).ContinueWith(result => OnTaskCompleted(
                {
                   //omitted code
                }), new CancellationTokenSource().Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            }

            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                //omitted code
            }
        }

        private void ProcessOrder(Order order, int index)
        {
            //we process the order here
        }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your `ProcessCustomer` method return a `Task`, you can asynchronously wait for it's completion:

```
public Task ProcessCustomer(Customer customer)
{
     return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
     {
            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(customer.Orders, parOpts, (order, loopState) =>
                {
                    count = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
                    ProcessOrder(order, count);
                });
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
               //omitted code
            }

     }, cancelToken.Token).ContinueWith(result => OnTaskCompleted(
     {
       //omitted code
     }), new CancellationTokenSource().Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None,
         TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Now you can:

```
//I'm assuming this is an event handler.
private async void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvwCustomers.Items)
    {
        await customerPresenter.ProcessCustomer(item.Tag as Customer);
    }
}
```

As you're using .NET 4.0, you'll need to use [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) to make `async-await` available.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.2 things: 1) I am in .net 4 and cannot find Microsoft.BCL.Async do you have to download it? 2)The all process starts by a user pressing a button ,so it's not in an eventhandler but in a button click see modified code sample.

Comment: 1. Click on `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` in my example. 2. That IS an event handler :)

Comment: yeah youre right click is an eventhandler just meant a custom declared one

Comment: it says "This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010, and is only required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5, "

Comment: is there another way of doing it?

Comment: I see, you're using VS2010. It's only compatible with VS2012 and above. As a side note, I suggest you upgrade. VS2010 is a very old version.

Comment: @developer9969 The only other way is running it synchronously.

Comment: cannot upgrade ,I wish I could .My company has decided not to upgrade to 4.5 for the time being.It's not my decision

Comment: @developer9969 Upgrade to VS2012/2013, not .NET 4.5.

Comment: Cannot upgrade to any version of visual studio.I can only use vs 2010 for now

Comment: Which bit to run syncronously?

Comment: `ProcessCustomer`. Don't offload it to a background thread using `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Let the `Parallel.ForEach` run on the main thread.

Comment: thanks for your help so far but If I do just 
Parallel.ForEach(customer.Orders, parOpts, (order, loopState) =>
{
   count = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
   ProcessOrder(order, count);
});  
How do I know when it has finished? eg I want to fire an event when completed? Do I fire the event when outside loop?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` will block until the entire loop is complete.